# cppUnitTests for performance testing

Tags: c++, unit-testing, performance-testing, cppunit

We are evaluating CPPUnitTest framework to do some performance evaluation of a particular production by consuming its API. The test is expected to login into the application and then perform some activities and then logout. While I am aware of how to achieve this using cppUnit suite, the part that I am not aware completely is to know how to set up the suite so that 100 different logins happen in parallel. Do you suggest anything suitable for this.

We want to use cppUnitTest framework and pull off performance testing by letting around 100 users login into the application and do some activity and log out.

Thanks,
Pavan.

Comment: Unit tests should be for individual classes.  Performance and integration tests aren't usually done using a unit testing framework.  Depending on your app, I'd suggest JMeter or SOAP UI.

Comment: Mine is a rich java UI based application. I will consider your suggestions.

Comment: I only work with apps that have web interfaces.  We use Selenium to drive those.  I don't know what the best practice is for Swing.  Sorry I'm not more help.

Comment: Rich Java. That's what I always hated about object oriented programming. It ruined the notion of a classless society. Programming languages of the world unite! You have nothing to lose except your linked lists!

Comment: Programming language income disparity is an ongoing problem.  So good of you to point it out, @user4581301.